# "WHERE" clause with subqueries in "IN"

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause, impala

I'm trying (on Impala SQL) to get the rows that have the biggest/ smallest difference between two columns, and I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col1 - col2 IN ( SELECT MAX(col1-col2) 
                       FROM table, SELECT MIN(col1-col2) FROM table )
```

Using only one subquery works, but if I add both of them inside IN it gives an error.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: Can you please provide the error?

Comment: AnalysisException: Unsupported IN predicate with a subquery:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(col1 - col2) AS min_diff, MAX(col1 - col2) AS max_diff
  FROM table
) AS agg ON t.col1 - t.col2 IN (agg.min_diff, agg.max_diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 - col2 IN ( SELECT MAX(col1-col2) FROM table
  Union
  SELECT MIN(col1-col2) FROM table )
```

**-- update**
Use `rank` as follows:

```
SELECT t.*,
       Rank() over (order by col1 - col2) as rn,
       Rank() over (order by col1 - col2 desc) as rnd
  FROM table t) t
 Where rn = 1 or rnd = 1
```

Comment: nice idea, but not it says :AnalysisException: A subquery must contain a single select block

Comment: AnalysisException: Subqueries in OR predicates are not supported

Comment: Is window function allowed in your version of impala? Use the updated section.

Comment: i can't use the rank solution, there's a syntax error and i don't know what to correct

Answer (score 0):

in your case you cannot use "in" like that you need to join it together or union it as list. I'll show you some example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  col1 - col2 IN ( SELECT MAX(col1-col2) FROM table  union  SELECT MIN(col1-col2) FROM table)
```

hop it will help you.

Comment: I'm getting this error with UNION : AnalysisException: A subquery must contain a single select block

Comment: how about this code,
`with
t1 as (SELECT MAX(col1-col2) col FROM table1 union
  SELECT MIN(col1-col2) col FROM table1)
select * from table1 where col1 - col2 IN (select col from t1)`

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer using CTE as shown below:

```
with difference as
(
    select min(col1-col2) minDifference,max(col1-col2) maxDifference
    from table
)

select *
from table as t
join difference as d
where t.col1-t.col2 in (d.minDifference,d.maxDifference)
```